# Gamma function still hard for me

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, gamma-function

During my study I find a form for gamma function it was
$\Gamma (x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n! n^{x-1}}{x(x-1)(x-2)........(x+n-1)}$
And then by simplify this limit I get
 $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{x-1}}{{x+n-1\choose n}}$$      then I use Stirling's approximation and evaluate the limit to
$\ (x-1)! * e^{x-1} * (\frac{n}{n+x-1})^{x+n-1{\over2}}$$
What next I should do to get Gamma function from this limit ?

Comment: What do you mean by "\up n?"

Comment: I mean binomial coefficient

Comment: It seems your evaluation involves $(x+1)!$ where $x$ may not be an integer.  That is where the gamma function is hiding.